# nginx directory listing on Rocky Linux

Tags: nginx

Can anyone tell me why nginx on Rocky Linux 8 is not listing files and dirs under /some/dir/ ?

My config is:

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf


server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  some_name.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.some_name.com.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.some_name.com.log;


        root   /some/dir;
        location / {
                autoindex on;

        }
}
```

This file is displayed instead /some/dir/index.html. No directory listing and no error in the error log.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Resolution is to add this line into config: index index.html;
and delete the file from the directory.
Really tricky.

Comment: Could you update your answer to display the full, fixed config file?